# Caliburn Micro with Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf, Unable to include actionmessage in event trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, nuget, caliburn.micro

I am switching my old `System.Windows.Interactivity` nuget packages to `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf` 
.
This is leading to compilation errors for the following

```
<b:Interaction.Triggers>
  <b:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
     <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="Start"/>
  </b:EventTrigger>
</b:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Where ActionMessage is Caliburn.Micro.ActionMessage.

The error I am getting is the following

Error   XDG0048 The specified value cannot be assigned to the collection. The following type was expected: "TriggerAction".

How can I upgrade while maintaining functionality?

Comment: Check if you are using supported version of `Caliburn Micro` require for `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf`. Alternatively try with short syntax like `<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseEnter] = [Action Save]">`

Comment: @user1672994 I updated to the latest Caliburn.Micro, nothing happened. From what I see on the github, not supported yet. But
When you say switch to button syntax, that would replace the actionmessage? Where would that xaml go? I am a backend guy

Comment: According to this [commit](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/commit/19176c500299c809b97a8009d33f039b8194206e#diff-9f76cc3583ca6fbdb89b13c37f640553) and description, `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf` was added already and exists in `4.0.109-alpha` version of CM. You can use [`myget` feed](https://www.myget.org/feed/caliburn-micro-builds/package/nuget/Caliburn.Micro) to get an alpha version

Comment: @pavelanikhouski Alpha version. Not stable, not in Nuget yet

Comment: @JohnDemetriou yes, you're right, it isn't stable yet. You can use the stable 3.2.0 version or wait for stable 4.x version of CM :)

Comment: Ok. With 3.2, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `Caliburn.Micro` currently does not support the latest `Microsoft.Behaviors.Xaml.Wpf` Nuget package from microsoft until Version 4, which at the moment of writing is at alpha stage. My solution to this was to use `CallMethodAction` from `Microsoft.Behaviors.Xaml.Wpf` and later replace it with `InvokeCommandAction` which is prefered anyway since it is binding on commands instead of methods